# How to use c# variable with sql server query?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have to use "messageId" and "parrentId" c# variables in sql query, but when I use error raise: "Incorrect syntax near '.2'.".

How can I use "messageId" and "parrentId" in below query?

```
internal DataTable getAllMessages(string messageId, string parrentId)
{
    Query = "SELECT DISTINCT T1.* FROM mail_Reply T2 JOIN mail_Messages T1 ON (T2." 
          + messageId + "=T1." + messageId + " OR T2." + parrentId + "=T1." 
          + messageId + ")";
    return ExecuteDataTable();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: Can you give an example of what is in the variable please

Comment: Yes, variables contain integer values, example:2,3,4....

Comment: can you post the result of the variable "Query"?

Comment: Where are you passing the query

Comment: If you really do have numeric field names then you need to escape them in your SQL query. `SELECT SomeAlias.2` is not valid SQL. Your SQL string needs to be like `..T2.[" + messageId + "].. `.

Comment: Is Query some funky variable type or a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you column names are like integer values 1,2,3, then try this,

```
Query = "SELECT DISTINCT T1.* FROM mail_Reply T2 JOIN mail_Messages T1 ON (T2.[" 
          + messageId + "]=T1.[" + messageId + "] OR T2.[" + parrentId + "]=T1.[" 
          + messageId + "])";
    return ExecuteDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and build a query string like that - it opens you up to a vulnerablity known as SQL Injection - and that is something you need to go away and read about right now...

Once you're done with that, read about Command objects - SqlCommand and friends...

Alternatively, consider embracing Entity Framework...

Answer (score -4):

use `string.format` or build the `query` seperatly in a string variable and assign it to `Query`